# Echo ajax data in view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, select

I am new to ajax and i am studying . i searched but i could not get a solution . i want to select all the countries from my database and want to echo the result in a table . i got the result but i don't know how to echo it in view . Somebody please help me. thanks in advance.

My controller Ajax.php

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('Ajax/Ajax_view');
}
function Get_specific()
{
    $name=$this->input->post('name');
    $data['country']=$this->Ajax_m->select("countries");
    echo json_encode($data);
    $this->load->view('Ajax_view',json_encode($data));
}
```

my Model Ajax_m.php

```
function select($table){
    $query=$this->db->get($table);

    return $query->result();
}
```

My View Ajax_view.php

```
<html>
<head>
                                                                                          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    
   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#data').hide();
    $('#sub').click(function(event){

      event.preventDefault();
      var name=$('#name').val();
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/Ajax/Get_specific/",
         datatype : 'html',
         data : { name: name },
         success:function(res){
 $('#data').show();
alert('done')
}      
      });  

  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo form_open('Ajax/insert'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub"><br>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <div id="data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>

            <?php 
            if(isset($query)):
            foreach ($query as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;
            endif;?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can return from your controller the html page (the table) and then append it $("#data").append(res) or something like that.

Comment: replace `$('#data').show();` with `$('#data').html(res).show();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/Ajax/Get_specific/",
     datatype : 'html',
     data : { name: name },
     success:function(res){
    $('#data').html(res).show();
    alert('done')
}
```

difficult to know exactly what you want here, but all i've done, is in the success of the ajax call, adding `res` to the element before showing it.

edit: if you don't want to lose anything already in the element, you could always use `.append()` rather than `.html()`